# Cannot connect to server from another server ftp php

Tags: php, ftp

I work with 2 servers one is my production server other is my resource server.

I cannot connect to my resource server from my production server over ftp.
I can connect to other servers from my production server.
I can also connect to my resource server from my localhost or filezilla.

I use this code to connect :

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("resource server ip", "21", "5");
if ($conn_id) {
    echo "connected";
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}
print_r(error_get_last());
```

I don't get any output when I run this script on server(no error).
On localhost it runs no problem.

What can be the problem with this? Is this something that server admin has to resolve? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there any proxy ?

Comment: Why are you not using `ftp_login()`? Do you not need to login to the other server?

Comment: no as far as I know @Random

Comment: Can you connect from the command line manually?

Comment: I will use `ftp_login()` but I need to connect first @Satisfaction

Comment: I don't have access to command line on my production server @syck

Comment: Hm.. you still have system() and its siblings. Is the production host a linux/unix box? If yes: What is output if you execute `system('ftp resource.server.ip');` in your PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check from commandline, whether it's a networking/OS issue or not.

So if you've got shell access to the production server try connecting to the resource server via the commandline ftp client.

If that does not work, you've got a network / firewall / access control problem, not related to php or your software, and you should talk to the sysadmin.

If it does work, then the problem is in your stuff, and you should set the log levels to high, and run this script from commandline, also check the logs of php, php-error, syslog and the resource servers ftp access log and syslog too.

Note: ftp is a not-too-exact beast, the servers and clients have a lot of workarounds built in to treat each other in a way, that works somehow. There could be issues from active (multiple back-and-forth connections) and passive mode (it's like http), also with ls formats and timestamps, timezones and ports.

Also some servers only support ftps (ftp with ssl) - which is not the same as sftp (file transfer over ssh - port 22).

Your production server probably has some firewall rules, and your connection get caught on that, to debug this, please use the commandline ftp client, and/or nmap / netcat.

Comment: Please note that the OP does not have command line access on his production server, and it is not even assured that it is a unix or linux machine, see comments to the question above.

Comment: My ftp user was only allowed to access server from whitelist of ip's. My work localhost happened to be one of them, that confused me. Thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: @syck windows has firewall, commandline, commandline ftp client, netcat, etc. too :) To connect Op could use remotedesktop, even ssh-to-powershell also. :) Of course syslog should be replaced. :)    I don't think my answer depends on any specific platform (besides of "check syslog" :) ).  On the other hand, the "check the resource servers ftp and syslog" was the key here, as it must have contained some events about the refused source ip address.

Comment: @KopiásPéter While nmap and netcat are available for windoze, they must be installed, which may not be possible at a remote machine. syslog on the other hand can be easily understood as a general term for the appropriate logging facilities. However, objection to your answer was not my intent.